# (REOPENED) "I want to help my boss who is burning out" doesn't have a "goal we can address"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question ([My manager is burning out, how can i help?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/91219/3192)) was closed as "questions require a goal we can address". The title makes the goal amply clear (OP wants to help the boss who is burning out), so I assume this means it is a goal "we" cannot address? Why not?

Comment: Voted to reopen

Comment: Hmm strange, I am not among the reopen voters. I am fairly sure I had voted to reopen before making this post. Never mind, question is reopened now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been reopened.